# Convert a list of list of strings into ndarray of floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings like the following:

```
['0.20115899', '0.111678', '0.10674', '0.05564842', '-0.09271969', '-0.02292056', '-0.04057575', '0.2019901', '-0.05368654', '-0.1708179']
['-2.17182860e-01', '-1.04081273e-01', '7.75325894e-02', '7.51972795e-02', '-7.11168349e-02', '-4.75254208e-02', '-2.94160955e-02']
etc.
etc.
```

List's name is `data_det`. I did the following to find the types:

```
for item in data_det:
      print(type(item))
      for it in item:
           print(type(it))
```

I got

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
etc.
```

I tried to convert it into `ndarray`.

```
data_det = numpy.asarray(data_det, dtype=np.float)
```

But got the error:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Ideally I want each value to be converted to float. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: `x = np.array([value for value in values], np.float)` try that. Values being your strings.

Comment: Please add to the question how `data_det` looks like

Comment: @Raymond It is not a single list. It is list of list.

Comment: @GravityMass one second. You need to traverse a list of list then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
import numpy as np
l1 = ['0.20115899', '0.111678', '0.10674', '0.05564842', '-0.09271969', '-0.02292056', '-0.04057575', '0.2019901', '-0.05368654', '-0.1708179']
l2 = ['-2.17182860e-01', '-1.04081273e-01', '7.75325894e-02', '7.51972795e-02', '-7.11168349e-02', '-4.75254208e-02', '-2.94160955e-02']

l1 = np.array([float(i) for i in l1])
l2 = np.array([float(i) for i in l2])
print(l1.dtype)
```

**Output** :

```
float64
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to my comment and your comment. Since you said your data is in **list of a list** format. You need to traverse the list.

You use `np.float` to set the values incoming to a float type. Use `dtype=object` to set arbitrary types.

```
import numpy as np

# Traverse list of list
def traverse(o, tree_types=(list, tuple)):
    if isinstance(o, tree_types):
        for value in o:
            for subvalue in traverse(value, tree_types):
                yield subvalue
    else:
        yield o

# Your data
values = [('0.20115899', '0.111678'), ('0.211282', '0.342342')]
# Traverse data list of list
values = traverse(values)
# Loop through new values
x = np.asarray([float(value) for value in values], np.float)
# Output
print(x)
```